# For Terraform, where is a list of valid dimensions for the aws_cloudwatch_alarm_metric resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```
$ terraform -v
Terraform v0.14.6
```

I using resource [aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_metric_alarm) to create AWS alarms of course. For the `dimensions` parameter, the doc links you to [AWS Services That Publish CloudWatch Metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/aws-services-cloudwatch-metrics.html), but that page does NOT list valid values, nor did I find them on the subsequent "Documentation" links for each namespace on that page. Where can I find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **check docs** of the respective service you want metrics for.

For example, for [ECS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cloudwatch-metrics.html#available_cloudwatch_metrics), the dimensions are `ClusterName` and `ServiceName`.

For [RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-cloudwatch.html) you have `DBInstanceIdentifier`, `DatabaseClass` and few more.